# GCC compile static library that can be called two times

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, static-libraries

I need to include two times a static library ".a" in my code. When I do it, the linker find two times the global variable and the functions.

Is there a way to compile the static library so that can be included two times? Is there a way to link directly all the internal symbols?
I can change the name of the external API for both the library.

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't seem to make sense. Why would you need to link twice to the same thing?

Comment: You need to rename all non-static symbols, not just function names. Of course much better solution is to rewrite library to use caller-provided state instead of context-unaware global variables.

Comment: I have to call a mathematical library in parallel with different input data.
Unfurtunately I would not rename all the symbols because they are a lot. Isn't there a tool to do it automatically?